# send group sms using AT command

Tags: sms

How to send group sms using AT command?

Comment: would you mind writing some more details??

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't. SMS PDUs are addressed to one number only; if you use your phone to compose a message to a group of people it actually creates a copy of the PDU for each recipient.

Unless you have access to a number that will take a received message and forward it to a group, you are out of luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

this website has some good details of how to do it with hyperterminal or kermit

http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp

it works pretty well.  although if your going to send a bunch of messages you should use some software that understands how to talk to the modem.

http://wammu.eu/gammu/

works great.